# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room Api is not giving updated data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am Using Microsoft Graph to fetch list of rooms available for a tenant.
As per Documentation, List Palace Api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) should be used for this.

Now, I am facing problem with getting updated data using List Places api.
I have added few rooms to the tenant but those are not reflected as part of response for List places api.
However, findRooms api which is in Beta gives the updated response.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room (Production version)
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms (Beta version)

Since, I will be using this api in production I cannot use Beta version Apis.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Update: List Places api is returning updated response after approx 12 hours