# Is there a way to distinguish created and updated events in Delta query response of Microsoft Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to use Microsoft Delta query to sync the changes for calendar. However I am not able to distinguish "created Event" and "Updated Events" in the response. Is there a way to do that?

In recurring meeting it would be of great help to know this whether the meeting has been created or updated.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no noticable difference between the types of change in the Delta feed. It's up to the application using Delta to keep track of resources it already "has seen" and then use that information as a comparison base to determine whether a change is an update or a creation.

Comment: could you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637674/https-graph-microsoft-com-v1-0-places-microsoft-graph-room-api-is-not-giving-u

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, I don't know much about those APIs. But I'm sure the team who owns it will eventually reply?

Comment: I have a product release coming up in 3 weeks and that Api is crucial. I have posted that query 1 week back but have not received any update. Hence,  I asked you as you were mostly active for all my queries.